"getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia
I get the following error in the command line when having ssr-started (laravel 11 + vue + inertia) and trying to navigate after php artisan Inertia:start-ssr and after npm run build:
The server starts without errors, the error appears when navigating, and apparently the app works, it's just the error message that appears in the backend, and I don't understand why:
 "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?
This will fail in production.
    at useStore (file://.../node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs:1741:19)
    at setup (file://.../bootstrap/ssr/assets/App-c081f20a.js:25:19)
    at _sfc_main.setup (file://...bootstrap/ssr/assets/App-c081f20a.js:55:23)
    at callWithErrorHandling (...node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:203:19)

navigating the Error Call Stack, the App-c018...js looks in short way like this:
const _sfc_main = /* @__PURE__ */ defineComponent({
  __name: "App",
  __ssrInlineRender: true,
  setup(__props) {
    console.log("App vue start");
    createPinia();
    const store = useAppStore();

I can't see where I additionally have to include pinia. Without the ssr i get no errors, it's just with the ssr started that the error appears, and I understand also where the error comes from, but I don't get why it fails or where I'd have to include pinia aditionally to avoid the error, as I cannot reference the app itseld in the App.vue for obvious reasons.
My ssr.js
    import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue';
    import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer';
    import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
    import createServer from '@inertiajs/vue3/server';
    import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
    import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
    import {createPinia} from "pinia";
    const pinia = createPinia();
    
    const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';
    
    createServer((page) =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
        resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./pages/**/*.vue')),
        setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
                .use(plugin)
                .use(ZiggyVue, {
                    ...page.props.ziggy,
                    location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.location),
                })
                .use(pinia);
        },
    })
);

The main.js and app.js both include pinia references and work fine.

You can try to move the line .use(pinia) further up, to have it as 1st or 2nd use entry. If either of the two plugins before it accesses anything from a Pinia store, it will result in the error you see ("Are you trying to use a store before calling app.use(pinia)?"),

ok, funnily strange at first tests it didn't work, but after some other changes it seemed to solve the issue!
return createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
.use(pinia)
.use(plugin)
